# Why won't my button change state after adding a class?

Tags: jquery, button, input, flip

I have a button which I created using the `<input>` tag and some jQuery/CSS to style it and make it functional.

My problem is that I cannot get my button to rotate upon clicking it, though I have added the `flip` function to it there. What could be the issue? Am I doing this wrong, or missing something? Is there an easier alternative I can try? I just want it to flip down when clicking on it from its current state which is shown in the input value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.myInnerBtn').click(function() {
    $(".blogs").slideToggle("slow", function() {
      $(".myInnerBtn").toggleClass('flip');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="innerbuttonwrapper1">
    <input type="button" value="►" class="myInnerBtn" style="background:none; font-family:Overpass, Arial, Verdana; font-size:18px; border:none; cursor:pointer; color:#741dff;" />
    <a class="blogs" href="iwriteonwheels.com/post/190161104157/tbt-ace-of-base" style="display:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;TBT: Ace of Base</a>
    <br>
    <p>
        <a class="blogs" href="iwriteonwheels.com/post/190002799642/2020" style="display:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2020</a>
        <br><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it the `flip` class that performs the rotation? If so, we need to see that CSS code (along with all the relevant HTML so we can create an executable example) included in the question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes it is. Ok I will try to copy/paste it for you here:

.flip {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

That's the CSS to the flip class. And here is the relevant HTML etc...

<a class="blogs" href="https://iwriteonwheels.com/post/190161104157/tbt-ace-of-base" style="display:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;TBT: Ace of Base</a><br><p>
  
<a class="blogs" href="https://iwriteonwheels.com/post/190002799642/2020" style="display:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2020</a><br><br><br>

Hope this helps. Please let me know if more is needed. Thanks.

Comment: Please use the `edit` link under the question to add more information as code in comments is almost unreadable.

Comment: if the `.blog`-element does not exist, the `slideToggle` function will not be run, meaning the callback is not executed that toggles the Class. Do you have a .blog element?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ok, let me redo that. It looks like a bunch of blob lol... 


The CSS to the flip class:

.flip {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

Comment: The jQuery: 

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.myInnerBtn').click(function () {
        $(".blogs").slideToggle("slow", function () {
            $(".myInnerBtn").toggleClass('flip');
       });
    });
});
</script>

Comment: And the relevant HTML:

<div class="innerbuttonwrapper1">
<input type="button" value="►" class="myInnerBtn" style="background:none; font-family:Overpass, Arial, Verdana; font-size:18px; border:none; cursor:pointer; color:#741dff;" />
</div>

<a class="blogs" href="https://iwriteonwheels.com/post/190161104157/tbt-ace-of-base" style="display:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;TBT: Ace of Base</a><br><p>
  
<a class="blogs" href="https://iwriteonwheels.com/post/190002799642/2020" style="display:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2020</a><br><br><br>
</div>

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I do have a .blog element yes. Here is the CSS part of that



.blogs {
    list-style-type:disc;
    list-style-position: inside;
    font-family:Overpass, Arial, Verdana;
    font-size:18px;
    z-index:50000;
    color:black;
    position:absolute;
    width:500px;
    left:30px;
}

Comment: @Ladan You have two elements with the blog class. Which means your callback will be called twice (two elements get slideToggled). That means the class flip is toggled in and toggled out again right away.

Comment: Thank you for the edit to my code. As I mentioned, I'm new here, so first time doing this.

Comment: @user3154108 hi. Ok so, how does this help with the problem I have with the button? What is it that I need to do?

Comment: @Ladan I posten a reply with some working code that needs little rework of your original code

Comment: @user3154108 ok thanks. Will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity sake just add a case-ing instead of a toggle since you don't know how many elements might toggle your class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.myInnerBtn').click(function() {
    $(".blogs").slideToggle("slow", function() {
        if ($(".blogs").is(':visible'))
            $(".myInnerBtn").addClass('flip');
        else
            $(".myInnerBtn").removeClass('flip');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.flip { transform: rotate(90deg);}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="innerbuttonwrapper1">
    <input type="button" value="►" class="myInnerBtn" style="background:none; font-family:Overpass, Arial, Verdana; font-size:18px; border:none; cursor:pointer; color:#741dff;" />
    <a class="blogs" href="iwriteonwheels.com/post/190161104157/tbt-ace-of-base" style="display:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;TBT: Ace of Base</a>
    <br>
    <p>
        <a class="blogs" href="iwriteonwheels.com/post/190002799642/2020" style="display:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2020</a>
        <br><br><br>
</div>
```

Edit: To clearify, this anser still leaves the weakness of the slideToggle which will just toggle, if for some happenstance one of your .blogs is showing and the other is not, that will cause problems.

Comment: ~ This has fixed the issue. Thanks again. I will certainly have this in mind when creating more buttons like this.

Comment: hi, just a quick question. What do I need to add to my code for pushing down my archive once I click it open? Right now it overlaps with the next archive (2019)

Comment: @Ladan That sounds like CSS Issues. You probably use `position: absolute` somewhere, which collapses the height of the parent element. If your Archives use a static position, they could push the content below them out of the way.

Comment: ok so changing to static positioning will do that? I have all absolute positioning. I have done some reading that absolute positioning will not move contents down when clicked on.

Comment: I still don't know how to go about doing this.